# How to calculate one certain value from a rolling-window estimation in Stata

Tags: sorting, variables, stata

I'm using Stata to estimate Value-at-risk (VaR) with the historical simulation method. Basically, I will create a rolling window with 100 observations, to estimate VaR for the next 250 days (repeat 250 times). Hence, as I've known, the rolling window with time series command in Stata would be useful in this case. Here is the process:

Input: 350 values
1. Ascending sort the very first 100 values (by magnitude).
2. Then I need to take the 5th smallest for each window.
3. Repeat 250 times.
Output: a list of the 5th values (250 in total).

Sound simple, but I cannot do it the right way. This was my attempt below:

```
program his,rclass
         sort lnreturn
         return scalar actual=lnreturn in 5
         end
tsset stt
         time variable:  stt, 1 to 350
                delta:  1 unit

rolling actual=r(actual), window(100) saving(C:\result100.dta, replace) : his
(running his on estimation sample)
```

And the result is:

```
   Start  end      actual   
    1     100    -.047856   
    2     101    -.047856   
    3     102    -.047856   
    4     103    -.047856
   ....  .....    ......

   251    350    -.047856
```

What I want is 250 different 5th values in panel "actual", not the same like that.

Comment: Some confusion between variables (in Stata always columns in the dataset) and values. Please check edits do not disturb your meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and your correction as well. English is my second language, sorry if any annoys you. I will be more careful in the future!

Comment: No annoyance; just that it is in everyone's interests that your meaning be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want the 5th percentile of values in a window of 100. That should yield to `summarize, detail` or `centile`. I see no need to write a program.

Your bug is that your program `his` calculates the same thing each time it is called. There is no communication about windows other than what is explicit in your code. It is like saying

move here: now add 2 + 2

move there: now add 2 + 2

move to New York: now add 2 + 2

The result is invariant to your supposed position.

Note that I doubt that

```
return scalar actual=lnreturn in 5
```

really is your code. `lnreturn[5]` should work.

UPDATE You don't even need `rolling` here. Looping over data is easy enough. The data in this example are clearly fake.

```
clear

* sandpit 
set obs 500
set seed 2803
gen y = ceil(exp(rnormal(3,2)))
l y in 1/5

* initialise  
gen p5 = . 

* windows of length 100: 1..100, 101..200, ...  
quietly forval j = 1/401 { 
local J = `j' + 99 
su y in `j'/`J', detail 
replace p5 = r(p5) in `j' 
} 

* check first calculation 
su y in 1/100, detail 
l in 1/5
```

Comment: I guess you understand what I mean, I want the 5th smallest of values in each window of 100. I think I need to use a rolling-window if I want to repeat my process 250 times, right? I've tried the code lnreturn[5] as you've said but nothing's changed, sadly. Thank you for your help, anyways.

Comment: I've explained why your program didn't work: commenting that I would be surprised if it was you as reported it is a detail.

Comment: Sorry I cannot get your idea thoroughly, as I've learned to use Stata in a short time, but I really need it in my thesis. Could you explain in more detail and/or show me the whole code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've found the code: rolling lnreturn=r(c_1), window(100): centile lnreturn, centile(4.9504950495049504) help me get the 5th smallest results that I want, also it's shorter and simpler. (I also want to say thank you to the person who posted the second answer but then soon deleted it).

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but 16 decimal places do look silly.

Comment: Yeah, because the centile(5) command doesn't give me the right results. Also, my values have at least 6 decimal places so I need to use the precise one :)

Comment: Use a window of 101 and your results will change by more.

Comment: There's a difference between the 5th smallest of a window of 100 and the 5th smallest of a window of 101. Thus I need to use exactly 100 in my case.

Comment: That's my point in reverse. You are making arbitrary decisions, so making some of them to 16 decimal places seems especially arbitrary. But it's you who has to explain this in some presentation/paper/thesis/dissertation, not me.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding and thank you for your advice, Dr Cox.

Comment: I deleted the answer because I wasn't confident the _historical simulation method_ was correct as I had posted it. The command was fairly easy: `rolling cent=r(c_1), window(#) clear: centile <somevar>, centile(5)`

Comment: You helped me a lot! I've almost despaired of trying. Thank you, sincerely!